# Error guardando imagen en un objeto ImageView con JavaFX y sceneBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

estoy haciendo una aplicación gráfica de escritorio bastante simple para manejo de imágenes y, estoy usando JavaFX, además de su sceneBuilder.
La idea es, al darle un botón que aparezca un FileChooser, escoger la imagen y que se muestre una ventana nueva con toda la imagen de fondo sobre ella el problema es que al hacer me da un error que no logro identificar.
Edit: He descubierto que si abro la imagen en la misma ventana no hay error, solo al hacerlo en una nueva.
Este es mi código.[image: Codigo]

Errores: [image: Errores]

SceneBuilder: [image: SceneBuilder]

Answer (score 1):

Para javafx evita usar las herramientas de AWT(BufferedImage)
Hay una clase nueva para ello.

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

Image image1 = new Image("/flower.png", true);
Image image2 = new Image("my/res/flower.png", 100, 150, false, false);
Image image3 = new Image("http://sample.com/res/flower.png", 100, 0, false, false);
Image image4 = new Image("file:flower.png", 0, 100, false, false);
```

Esto luego lo puedes colocar en un ImageView. Mi sugerencia es que revises

```
javafx.scene.image.WritableImage
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar el siguiente método:

```
public void abrirVentana(ActionEvent event) { 
       FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new 
       FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Archivos JPG", "*.JPG");

       FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
       fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG);
    
       File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
       if (file != null) {
           ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
           imageView.setImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
                
           final BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(imageView);
           borderPane.setCenter(imageView);
                
           final ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane(borderPane);
           root.setFitToHeight(true);
           root.setFitToWidth(true);
                
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
           stage.show();
      }
}
```

Si se selecciona una imagen se abrirá una segunda ventana mostrandola.